# Adding another field to form in Meteor TODO app?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm very new to Meteor and following along in the official docs their TODO APP. So far so good but I want to add a **second input** to the example which has only a place for inputing and storing "*text*." I am trying to add a "*quantity*" field so that a user can input text and quantity.

If I go through the command line and type:

`db.tasks.insert({text: "apples", quantity: 4, createdAt: new Date() });`

I can get the quantity field to correctly populate. However, I cannot get the data into the quantity field when submitting through the DOM. Here is my HTML:

```
<head>
  <title>Todo List</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <h1>Todo List</h1>
      <form class="new-task">
        <label for="text">TEXT:</label>
        <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Type to add new tasks" />
        <label for="text">NUMBER:</label>
        <input type="text" name="quantity" placeholder="Quantity" />
        <input type="submit" class="submit"/>
      </form>

    </header>


    <ul>
      {{#each tasks}}
<!--       this inserts the template called "task" -->
        {{> task}}
      {{/each}}
    </ul>

  </div>

</body>

<template name="task">
   <li class="{{#if checked}}checked{{/if}}">
  <input type="checkbox" checked="{{checked}}" class="toggle-checked" />
    <span class="text">{{text}}{{quantity}}</span>
           <button class="delete">&times;</button>


  </li>
</template>
```

Here is my JS:

```
Tasks = new Mongo.Collection("tasks");

if (Meteor.isClient){
  //This code only runs on client
  Template.body.helpers({
    tasks: function () {
        // Show newest tasks at the top
      return Tasks.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}});
    }
  });
  Template.body.events({
    "submit .new-task": function (event) {
      // Prevent default browser form submit
      event.preventDefault();
       console.log(event)

      // Get value from form element
      var text = event.target.text.value;
      var quantity = event.target.text.value;


      // Insert a task into the collection
      Tasks.insert({
        text: text,
        quantity: quantity,
        createdAt: new Date() // current time
      });

      // Clear form
      event.target.text.value = "";
    }
  });

   Template.task.events({
    "click .toggle-checked": function () {
      // Set the checked property to the opposite of its current value
      Tasks.update(this._id, {
        $set: {checked: ! this.checked}
      });
    },
    "click .delete": function () {
      Tasks.remove(this._id);
    }
  });

}
```

You'll see that I have not completed the tutorial and have made some modifications to the HTML.

I'm pretty sure I'm messing up my JS. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
var text = event.target.text.value;
var quantity = event.target.text.value;
```

These two are going to be the same.

Instead use:

```
var text = $('input[name="text"]').val();
var quantity = $('input[name="quantity"]').val();
```

Comment: For some reason the jQuery is preventing both values from being stored now but in the actual TODO list view, it adds a blank field. I checked in the DB and a blank field is also being added there too.

Comment: My apologies, should have used `.val()` instead of `.value`

Answer (score 1):

Just playing around with the JS, I got it to post when I changed this:

```
   // Get value from form element
      var text = event.target.text.value;
      var quantity = event.target.text.value;
```

To this:

```
  // Get value from form element
  var text = event.target.text.value;
  var quantity = event.target.quantity.value;
```